Python (multiprocessing/tqdm) - How do I track the progress of a for loop within a multiprocessing function?
I am currently trying to track the progress of several instances of a function, each instance iterating inside the function itself. I am using multiprocessing to initiate the several instances of said function, and I have been trying to use tqdm to monitor the progress of each of those function instances.
(Note: I am using a jupyter notebook for my main script, and storing the function in an external "functions.py" file. This is required for multiprocesses to work within the notebook.)
Functions.py
The function executes an external program that performs an iterative calculation, giving an output after each iteration. I capture this output within a for loop that itself iterates only when a new output occurs
def run_exe_instance(args):
    import os
    import subprocess
    #do stuff
    os.chdir(directory)
    exe_process = subprocess.Popen(["program.exe"],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    os.chdir(notebookFolder) #Switches directory back to notebook folder
    for i1 in range(number_of_exe_iterations): #THE LOOP TO TRACK ITERATIONS OF
        if (line := exe_process.stdout.readline()) != "":
            pass
    print("Finished!")

Main

import os
import subprocess
import multiprocessing
import Functions as f

if __name__ == "__main__":
    __spec__ = None            #bugfix for iPython/Jupyter Notebook
    args = [(some args,),(some more args,)]
    pool = mp.Pool(len(args))
    pool.starmap(f.run_exe_instance, args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

This code works for actually executing multiple "program.exe" instances and then moving on when they're finished. However, I cannot figure out how to implement multiple progress bars to monitor the simultaneous progress of the processes.
I first tried using tqdm inside the function. However, any outputs inside the function are printed to the "Anaconda Prompt" command prompt window I used to launch my jupyter notebook. Within this window, the progress bars do not work.
def run_exe_instance(args):
    import os
    import subprocess
    #do stuff
    os.chdir(directory)
    exe_process = subprocess.Popen(["program.exe"],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    os.chdir(notebookFolder) #Switches directory back to notebook folder
    for i1 in tqdm(range(number_of_exe_iterations),desc=filename,position=bar_position): #THE LOOP TO TRACK ITERATIONS OF
        if (line := exe_process.stdout.readline()) != "":
            pass
    print("Finished!")

Following this failure, I tried passing a tqdm progress bar as an argument into the function, then updating its progress using pbar.update(). This works for non-multiprocessing functions, but multiprocessing throws a TypeError: cannot pickle '_hashlib.HMAC' object error back at me.
I have also tried using p_tqdm. However, the progress bars only iterate each time the function returns. In the case of my function, it does not complete until "program.exe" is complete.
Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

This answer doesn't solve the issue of using tqdm with multiprocessing, it is possible to solve it with semaphores and threads, but this question requires a different answer.
For running external executables you don't need to use multiprocessing, instead using a Threadpool is enough. you seem to need to use it to use os.chdir, but this is not needed, as subprocess.Popen has a cwd kwarg that you can use to specify the directory in which the process will spawn in.
import os
import subprocess
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import tqdm
import time

def run_exe_instance(args):
    import os
    import subprocess
    #do stuff
    directory = "some_dir" # use cwd kwarg of subprocess.Popen instead of using chdir
    # exe_process = subprocess.Popen(["program.exe"],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=directory)
    for i1 in tqdm.tqdm(range(10),position=args): #THE LOOP TO TRACK ITERATIONS OF
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Finished!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    __spec__ = None            #bugfix for iPython/Jupyter Notebook
    args = [(0,),(1,)]
    pool = ThreadPool(len(args))
    pool.starmap(run_exe_instance, args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

now you can safely create multiple bars using position argument of tqdm, see tqdm-Using multiple bars
